# SBT - how do I run flyway migrations and slick codegen against two databases?

Tags: scala, sbt, slick, flyway

I want to run flyway migrations against a test database when running tests. Otherwise, use a runtime database.

After numerous discussions and as a result of help I've received from the community, it has been suggested that what I want is unconventional.

I disagree. I think SBT has forced my discussions through a particular set of cognitive filters and bias to the point where what I want only SEEMS unconventional.

What I want to do is use a test database for migration and code generation when running tests, and a runtime database otherwise. That is patently NOT unconventional. I've done it in Maven and Gradle often - otherwise, how, exactly, am I supposed to actually TEST my migrations and codegen during development?

Given that we're talking SBT here:

- `compile` => run flyway migrations and generate slick code from `localhost:5432`
- `test` => run flyway migrations and generate slick code from `localhost:5434`

Where (in order):

- `compile` executes `flywayMigrate` + slick codegen + `compile` against `localhost:5432`
- `test` executes `flywayClean` + `flywayMigrate` + slick codegen + `compile` + `test` against `localhost:5434`

Both `compile:compile` and `test:compile` generated sources should be placed in `src_managed/main`.

Here's the working repository: https://github.com/rbellamy/flyway-slick-codegen